# Pipeline code to get Jenkins job's build number?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I know that a Jenkins job's job number is just an environment variable, so if I'm writing pipeline code it'll be simply

```
def jobNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER
```

However, if I have 2 jobs where `job2` requires `job1`'s build number, how would I do it? Here's some sample/pesudo code.

```
job1:
// Set the current build's display name to the Gradle artifact version
dir(workSpace) {
  // Execute a Gradle task that gets the artifact version, e.g., 1.2.3
  currentBuild.displayName = sh(script: "./gradlew printVersion",
                                returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

So if one looks at `job1`'s page, the left pane will have the various Gradle versions that it built instead of the typical `#BUILD_NUMBER`.

```
2.1.1
2.1.0
1.2.3
1.1.0
```

Now I want `job2` to parse `job1`'s builds to get the build number associated with version `1.2.3`. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: I assume job2 and job1 builds are somehow related, either a common trigger, or job1 triggers job2. The nature of that relationship is critical here, could you add it to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the code by @chris will do the job, the build can be achieved in a more Groovy way using the following shortened syntax:

```groovy
// If version is not an exact match you can use: it.displayName.contains('gradle_version')
def buildNumber = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).find{it.fullName == 'job_name'}.builds.find{it.displayName == 'gradle_version'}.number
```

If you are not sure the version exists, you can use the following:

```groovy
def build = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).find{it.fullName == 'job_name'}.builds.find{it.displayName == 'gradle_version'}
assert build : "A build matching version gradle_version was not found"
def buildNumber = build.number
```

Something to notice is that the `find` method will return the first option that matches the condition, in this case it is the latest build that has the matching Gradle version.
In case you need something different than the latest matching version you can use the `findAll` method to get all matching builds and than choose the relevant one based on the desired logic.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a C/C++ programmer so I code like one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `job1` does our build and displays the Gradle artifact version. Each build stores a set of build artifacts unique to the build. When `job2` runs, it presents the user with a list of versions from the `job1` builds. Based on the user selection, `job2` deploys the set of archived artifacts that `job1` built. So when it runs, I want it to read `job1`'s archived artifacts based particularly on the build number.

I found an existing job in our Jenkins setup that does something similar. I modified it to do what I want.

```
  import hudson.model.*
  Integer getBuildNumberFromVersion(final String version) {
    def buildJob = "fullPath/job1"
    Job job = null
    for (Job j in Hudson.instance.getAllItems(Job.class)) {
      if (j.fullName == buildJob) {
        job = j
        break
      }
    }
    if (job == null) {
      throw new Exception("Could not find $buildJob")
    }

    Integer buildNumber = -1
    for (build in job.getBuilds()) {
      if (build.displayName.contains(version)) {
        buildNumber = build.getNumber()
        break
      }
    }
    if (buildNumber == -1) {
      throw new Exception("Could not find matching build number for $version")
    }
    return buildNumber
  }
```

Comment: Can also be done in a more groovy way using the following line: `Jenkins.instance.getItem('job_name').builds.find{it.displayName.contains('_gradle_version')}.number`

Comment: Post this and I'll accept it as an answer.